# How to test my solution (contest)?

Tags: testing

I made a code for contest, I am getting 'WA' but I am sure that my code is correct . So before I complain admin, how could I be sure that my code is actually correct and not that problem test data is incorrect? Here's the [question](http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2012/zco2012/zco2012-2a.php) and this is my [solution](http://pastebin.com/fZuVPAYf) in c++ , so can anyone suggest methods of testing one's own solution or can anybody supply test input where my solution produces wrong answer?

Comment: Still , couldnt debug ? nevermind lets see if we could find such a test input , usually its our solution which is wrong not contest test data :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh , god you should check properly , i found another input which gives wrong output ( i told you usually test inputs are correct and we are usually wrong :D) . 
 For input "1 2 1 3 4 2" your code outputs "1 4 2" which is certainly wrong , it should be "2 4 2" .

Answer (score 1):

You have several examples inside the question explanation you can use to test your code:

> For instance, the alternating depth of (([]))[[[()]]] is 2, the
>   maximum number of symbols between a matched pair () is 6 and the
>   maximum number of symbols between a matched pair [] is 8.

And

> **Sample Input**
>   14
>   1 1 3 4 2 2 3 3 3 1 2 4 4 4
>   **Sample Output**
>   2 6 8

You can also invent some yourself, count the depth and maximum number of symbols and use that as input.

Moreover, it is said in the question that

> The time limit for this task is 1 second. The memory limit is 32MB.

Are you sure your code didn't take more than a second on one of the very big inputs, with `N` is close to `10^5`?

If the tests don't pass, its **highly probable that the problem is in your code** and not in the automated checker.

Comment: i have already tested them , and my code works correctly for them , and i also have made about 40 different test inputs myself but couldn't find a test input where my code prints a wrong answer ! Thats why i have turned up to stackflow !And i am very sure it will run in time limit , as its time complexity is O(n) .